# Qt application deployment - doesn't run, yet no error messages

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to develop a 32-bit Qt 5.3 application compiled with MingW 4.8.2 on Windows 8 and tried to deploy the application. I added all of the necessary release version DLL files the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) asked for, yet the application doesn't run. No error messages are shown either. On startup, the application just appears in the Task Manager for a few seconds and then disappears without any notice.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Does it run in Qt Creator? If so, follow the instructions at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows . Note that Dependency Walker might not find all DLLs.

Comment: To clarify, Dependency Walker does not find plugin DLLs unless you select "Profile" -> "Start Profiling..."

Comment: Dependency Walker will not find DLLs which are loaded dynamically, such as the platform library, for which you will not get any error message if missing either.

Comment: Did you deploy platforms/qwindows.dll?

Comment: The project did run in QtCreator. I had deployed the platforms/qwindows.dll, but somehow missed the "start profiling" step. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently having quite a few kinds of deployment problems I find the article [Qt for Windows - Deployment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) very useful. Both static and dynamically linked Qt deployment kinds we can do now and the simpler case which is dynamic is almost always fully resolved by windeployqt utility (Windows Deployment Tool). As long as you've already solved that problem you probably don't feel like reading that article but with any new component added you don't need to trace DLLs or plug-in dependencies, just do it as they suggest.